# using as.formula() in glmer and dredging it with MuMIn

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to use the `dredge` function from the `MuMIn` package, as follows. Since I want to run it for different datasets, I am using a function, that takes in the vector of covariates and the formula is created from this vector within the function.

```
require(lme4);require(MuMIn)
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
zrand <- sample(letters, 100, replace =T)
yind <- sample(1:1000, size=100, replace=T)
mydata <- data.frame(yind, x1, x2, zrand)
vars <- c('x1', 'x2')
```

When I run it this way, I get the error that symbol is not subsettable. I think it has to do with using `vars` in the formula, though the lmer runs fine

```
myformula <- as.formula(paste('yind~',paste(vars,collapse='+'),'+(1|zrand)'))

mylmer1 <- lmer(myformula, mydata, gaussian)

dredge(mylmer1)
```

Error in terms(as.formula(formula(x))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'terms': Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

But this works fine, for a reason I do not understand fully, but has to do with the scope of the dredge function. (I may be totally off the mark here)

```
mylmer2 <- lmer(as.formula(paste('yind~',paste(vars,collapse='+'),'+(1|zrand)')), 
              mydata, gaussian)

dredge(mylmer2)
```

What I doing in my analysis is more akin to this, where lmer and dredge are run inside a function

```
myfn <- function(fnd,fnvar){
  myformula <- as.formula(paste('yind~',paste(fnvar,collapse='+'),'+(1|zrand)'))
    print(myformula)

mylmer1 <- lmer(myformula, fnd, gaussian)
    print(mylmer1@call)
  print(dredge(mylmer1))

  mylmer2 <- lmer(as.formula(paste('yind~',paste(fnvar,collapse='+'),'+(1|zrand)')), 
                fnd, gaussian)

  print(mylmer2@call)
  print(dredge(mylmer2))
  }

myfn(fnd=mydata, fnvar=vars)
```

Dredgin only lmer1 gives this error:

```
Error in print(dredge(mylmer1)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in terms(as.formula(formula(x))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'terms': Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Dredging only lmer2, gives the following error

```
Error in print(dredge(mylmer2)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in terms(as.formula(formula(x))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'terms': Error in paste(fnvar, collapse = "+") : object 'fnvar' not found.
```

Is there a way to get around this? Is this a necessary limitation of the dredge function?

Comment: this works for me with the development version of `lme4` (1.1-1); what version of `lme4` are you using?  (I would also encourage you to use `lmer` instead of `glmer(...,family=gaussian)` ...)

Comment: thanks @BenBolker .My `lme4` version is ‘0.999999.2’. I updated the `lme4` but probably didn't `unloadNamespace`, so I was stuck with an older version!My data is binary so I am using `glmer(family=binomial)`. Here it was only an example but will edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: Strange! I updated `lme4` to 1.0.5. Now I get: "Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “mer” object: Slot L must be a monotonic LL' factorization of size dims['q']" when running the `lmer` itself

Comment: The dev version 1.1-1 works fins though. Thanks again!

Comment: your problem with 1.0.5 is not having re-installed `Matrix` and `RcppEigen` first ...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275664/how-to-use-lmer-inside-a-function). Apparently it is called a "deparse-substitute trick".

Do

```
mylmer1@call$formula <- tmp.formula
```

before dredging the `mer` object

Missed it as I thought it was something to do with MuMIn.

Comment: lme4 version 1.1-1 works fine without having to "deparse-substitute"