# Unexpected error when looping the glmer function with the effects package

Tags: r, model, lapply, lme4

I am trying to pass the `effect` function from the [*effects*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) package together with a `(gl)merMod` object from the [*lme4*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) package through a `lapply` loop and encounter an error I do not expect. It seems that the `effect` function fails to look for objects inside the loop. **What do I do wrong and how to get the loop working without manually placing the data frame into the workspace?**

```
library(lme4)
library(reshape2)
library(effects)

dat <- data.frame(var = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 100), treat = rep(c("T1", "T2"),
each = 150), rand =  rep(c("B", "C", "A"), 100), value = rep(c(1,0), 150))

lapply(levels(dat$treat), function(k) {
  y <- subset(dat, treat == k)
  mod <- glmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y, family = binomial)
  })
## Works

lapply(levels(dat$treat), function(k) {
  y <- subset(dat, treat == k)
  mod <- glmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y, family = binomial)
  effects::effect("var", mod)
})
## Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'y' not found

y <- subset(dat, treat == "T1")
mod <- glmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y, family = binomial)
effects::effect("var", mod)
## Works

lapply(levels(dat$treat), function(k) {
  y <- subset(dat, treat == k)
  mod <- glmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y, family = binomial)
  effects::effect("var", mod)
})
## Works, because object y is in the workspace
```

Comment: This is apparently not the solution, but **using a glm() model worked** for me: `lapply(levels(dat$treat), function(k) {
  y <- subset(dat, treat == k)
  mod <- glm(value ~ var , data = y, family = binomial)
  effects::effect("var", mod)
})` so it might be a specific problem in the effects-package in conjunction with glmer

Comment: @maller Thanks! So this is a `lme4` problem...I edited my question. Btw, `lapply(levels(dat$treat), function(k) {y <- subset(dat, treat == k); mod <- lmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y);  effects::effect("var", mod)})` produces the error.

Comment: You might want to look at [link](https://github.com/cran/effects/blob/master/R/effectsmer.R) but I am not capable to find an explanation

Comment: Similar error occurs, if you try to use `effects` inside a function. For that particular case the substitute-deparse trick seems to fix the issue. Did not work for this example, however. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275664/how-to-use-lmer-inside-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem (using lm with a model.matrix) where effects worked fine on its own, but then not did not work in my lapply loop.

I tried rewriting my code with a for loop instead which solved my problem. Since the for loop assigns objects to the global environment each time, you would not have to place them there manually.

With your example, the for loop does not throw an error, although now you will need to assign the output to something:

```
for(k in levels(dat$treat)) {
  y <- subset(dat, treat == k)
  mod <- glmer(value ~ var + (1|rand), data = y, family = binomial)
  effects::effect("var", mod)
  }
```